# How to start bokeh server in dev mode?

Tags: bokeh

I can start the server with

```
bokeh serve myapp/
```

but

```
bokeh serve --dev myapp/
```

returns

> ERROR: list index out of range

I am running bokeh 1.1.0

Comment: I can't reproduce a problem on OSX with the example apps (single module, or directory) so it's impossible to speculate without more information.

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong order? I'm only able to reproduce the error by using `bokeh serve --dev script.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dev mode can be started by using this commmand (Tested with Bokeh 1.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.0.4):

```
bokeh serve script.py --dev --show
bokeh serve directory/ --dev --show #(if your script is called main.py)
```

The probblem with your command is that you are using the wrong order. You have to specify the directory/script before you use the dev mode option.

More information can be found by using `bokeh serve --help`. It is not listed on the [documentation page](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/command/subcommands/serve.html). (Thanks for correcting me @bigreddot)

Comment: There is a `--dev` mode, but that page was neglected to be updated tp reflect it. However, you can see it in `bokeh serve --help` Please help the project and make an issue (or PR) regarding this.

Comment: i looked at `bokeh serve --help` before I posted this question and it suggested to me to use the arguments ought to be used in the order I stated in the question.

Comment: I think this is actually a bug! The order should not matter (but I can confirm it does). Please file an issue on GitHub with this information: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues You could mention the docs needing update there as well